# Tkinter LabelFrames don't show up

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-class

When i want to layout my frames the Labels don't show up. I can't seem to solve it. For some reason it does show op the entries that i've made. Can somebody please help me.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class main_screen():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Roboframe")
        self.master.geometry("650x650")
        self.create_frames()
        self.create_entries()

    def create_frames(self):
        self.top = Frame(self.master).grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.bottom = Frame(self.master).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.set_paths = LabelFrame(self.master, text="Set Path", padx=10, pady=10).grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.options = LabelFrame(self.master, text="Options", padx=10, pady=10).grid(row=0,column=0)

    def create_entries(self):
        python_path = StringVar(self.set_paths, "C:/Python37/python.exe")
        robot_path = StringVar(self.set_paths, "C:/ws/cmge.automation/RobotFrameworkCMGE")
        self.set_path_python = Entry(self.set_paths, width=60, textvariable=python_path).grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.set_path_robot = Entry(self.set_paths, width=60, textvariable=robot_path).grid(row=1, column=0)

root = tk.Tk()
app = main_screen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[Output of code shown above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDiUt.png)

[The thing i'm rewritting the code for because it is a mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cgdp.png)

The second picture i've also made myself. But the code is a giant mess.

Comment: `grid` method will return `None`. For example, initialize the label frame and save its reference in `self.set_paths` then use it to call ``grid``. ``self.set_paths = LabelFrame(self.master, text="Set Path", padx=10, pady=10);self.set_paths.grid(row=0,column=0)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make an object of the widget not the grid function of the widget. Grid returns nothing so naturally none of them will show up. I believe this is what you wanted:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class main_screen():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Roboframe")
        self.master.geometry("650x650")
        self.create_frames()
        self.create_entries()

    def create_frames(self):
        # you have grided all of your frames and label frames on the same row and column
        self.top = Frame(self.master)
        self.top.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.bottom = Frame(self.master)
        self.bottom.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.set_paths = LabelFrame(self.master, text="Set Path", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.set_paths.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.options = LabelFrame(self.master, text="Options", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.options.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def create_entries(self):
        python_path = StringVar(self.set_paths, "C:/Python37/python.exe")
        robot_path = StringVar(self.set_paths, "C:/ws/cmge.automation/RobotFrameworkCMGE")
        self.set_path_python = Entry(self.set_paths, width=60, textvariable=python_path)
        self.set_path_python.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.set_path_robot = Entry(self.set_paths, width=60, textvariable=robot_path)
        self.set_path_robot.grid(row=1, column=0)

root = tk.Tk()
app = main_screen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Also a couple of things:

- You have imported tkinter twice in two different ways, just use one of them
- You are griding both of the LabelFrames and frames on the same row and column but since "self.options" does not contain anything it is not going to show up, be careful later on

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! I've now imported tkinter once. About the `options`. I'm going to fill that one later thank you for notifying me. As for the `Frame` and `LabelFrame`. I thought when i want to make grided layout i can make 2 frames which i can fill with all the necessary stuff to create something that is easier to layout. Or do i need just the `LabelFrames` to achieve the same thing?. Next to the items in the `LabelFrame set_paths` i wanted to add a image. without the label Set Paths above it. So i thought a need a diffrent frame where i can add the image inside

Comment: Yes, it is possible but just remember when putting both the frames and labelframes on the same row and column they are going to overlap, Also when using frames as containers I personally prefer .pack compared to grid because grid isn't the best for placing frames in my opinion and you might want to add a "sticky" or "rowspan" or "columnspan" keyword to the grid function of your frames. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

This will display both LabelFrames, the second with a dummy Entry widget.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class main_screen():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Roboframe")
        self.master.geometry("650x650")
        self.create_frames()
        self.create_entries()

    def create_frames(self):
        self.set_paths = LabelFrame(self.master, text="Set Path", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.set_paths.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.options = LabelFrame(self.master, text="Options", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.options.grid(row=1,column=0)
        
    def create_entries(self):
        python_path = StringVar(self.set_paths, "C:/Python37/python.exe")
        robot_path = StringVar(self.set_paths, "C:/ws/cmge.automation/RobotFrameworkCMGE")
        self.set_path_python = Entry(self.set_paths, width=60, textvariable=python_path)
        self.set_path_python.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.set_path_robot = Entry(self.set_paths, width=60, textvariable=robot_path)
        self.set_path_robot.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.test = Entry(self.options, width=60)
        self.test.grid(row=1, column=1)
        

root = tk.Tk()
app = main_screen(root)
root.mainloop()
```